# Get an ARM VM Status take WAY much longer than before

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine, azure-powershell

i'm facing a problem since last week. When i run this powershell command everything works well excepted now this command takes ~12seconds to complete.

```
(Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $Vm.ResourceName -Status).Statuses[1].DisplayStatus
```

Until last week, this simple code took less than a seconde to complete. Am i the only one facing this issue?

The problem is, i'am using this code in a larger script and this part (to get all Vm powerstate) take someting like 50 minutes to complete now, but ~3minutes before.

here is a sample of the code i'm using (i've just added a bunch of 'Measure-Command' to see what is going on)

```
#
# Status des VM
#
Write-Output "VM Status Start"
$TimeToGetVmList = Measure-Command {$VmList = Find-AzureRmResource -TagName "environnement" -TagValue $vmEnv | Where-Object {$_.ResourceType -like "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"}}
Write-Host "`n-Get The VmList $($TimeToGetVmList.Minutes):$($TimeToGetVmList.Seconds):$($TimeToGetVmList.Milliseconds) minutes" -ForegroundColor Cyan
if ($VmList) {
    $indexVMState = 1
    $TimeToAllVmStatus = Measure-Command {
        foreach ($Vm in $VmList) {
            <# debug: limit to 10 #>
            if ($indexVMState -le 10) {
                #Write-Host "`r$indexVMState/$($VmList.Count)" -NoNewline
                $TimeToGetVM = Measure-Command {$VmDetails = (Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $Vm.ResourceName)}
                Write-Host " -Get VM [$($Vm.ResourceName)/$($vm.ResourceGroupName)] $($TimeToGetVM.Minutes):$($TimeToGetVM.Seconds):$($TimeToGetVM.Milliseconds) minutes" -ForegroundColor Magenta
                $VmListTags = $VmDetails.Tags
                $TimeToGetThePowa = Measure-Command {$PowerState = ((Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $Vm.ResourceName -Status).Statuses[1].DisplayStatus)}
                Write-Host " -Get Status [$($Vm.ResourceName)/$($vm.ResourceGroupName)] $($TimeToGetThePowa.Minutes):$($TimeToGetThePowa.Seconds):$($TimeToGetThePowa.Milliseconds) minutes" -ForegroundColor Magenta
                <#  Write-Output "avant - $($Vm.ResourceName) - $PowerState" #>
                $OsProfile = $VmDetails |Select-Object @{l = 'OsType'; e = {$_.StorageProfile.osDisk.osType}}
                <#  Write-Output "avant - $($Vm.ResourceName) - $($OsProfile.OsType)" #>
                if ($PowerState -notcontains "VM running") {
                    if ($VmListTags -or $VmListTags.schedule -match "`"$dayToday`":" -or $VmListTags.startmwtf -and $WorkingDays -contains $dayToday) {
                        if ($VmListTags.Projet) {$ProjectName = $VmListTags.Projet}else {$ProjectName = "N.C."}
                        $MyTrashStatus = New-Object PSObject
                        $MyTrashStatus | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Environnement -Value $vmEnv
                        $MyTrashStatus | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "RG Name" -Value $vm.ResourceGroupName
                        $MyTrashStatus | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Serveur -Value $Vm.ResourceName
                        $MyTrashStatus | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Projet -Value $ProjectName
                        $MyTrashStatus | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Systeme -Value $OsProfile."OsType"
                        $MyTrashStatus | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Status -Value $PowerState
                        $vmsPowerState.Add($MyTrashStatus) | Out-Null
                    }
                }
                if ($OsProfile."OsType" -match "Windows") {$OsWin += 1} elseif ($OsProfile."OsType" -match "Linux") {$OsLin += 1}
                $indexVMState++
            }
        }
    }
    Write-Host "`n---Time to Get all VM status [$($indexVMState -1)Vm] $($TimeToAllVmStatus.Minutes):$($TimeToAllVmStatus.Seconds):$($TimeToAllVmStatus.Milliseconds) minutes" -ForegroundColor DarkRed
}
$VmStatusList = "$($VmList.Count) VM IaaS ($OsWin Windows & $OsLin Linux)"
if ($vmsPowerState.Count -ge 1) {
    $vmsPowerStateReport = $vmsPowerState | ConvertTo-HTML -fragment
}
else {
    $vmsPowerStateReport = "`t`tToutes les machines sont en etat RUNNING."
}
Write-Output "VM Status End"
```

And the output, as i see, when i request its status, it tooks like ~12seconds! ~_~

```
ALREADY logged in to Azure...
 User: blabla
 Subscription: blabla

Url Start
Url End
Backup Start
Backup End
VM Status Start

-Get The VmList 0:0:443 minutes
 -Get VM [-] 0:0:328 minutes
 -Get Status [-] 0:12:715 minutes
 -Get VM [-] 0:0:243 minutes
 -Get Status [-] 0:12:30 minutes
 -Get VM [-] 0:0:316 minutes
 -Get Status [-] 0:12:23 minutes
 -Get VM [-] 0:0:140 minutes
 -Get Status [-] 0:12:71 minutes
 -Get VM [-] 0:0:172 minutes
 -Get Status [-] 0:12:58 minutes
 -Get VM [-] 0:0:233 minutes
 -Get Status [-] 0:12:76 minutes
 -Get VM [-] 0:0:154 minutes
 -Get Status [-] 0:12:86 minutes
 -Get VM [-] 0:0:178 minutes
 -Get Status [-] 0:12:42 minutes
 -Get VM [-] 0:0:192 minutes
 -Get Status [-] 0:12:78 minutes
 -Get VM [-] 0:0:185 minutes
 -Get Status [-] 0:12:39 minutes

---Time to Get all VM status [10Vm] 2:3:426 minutes
VM Status End
Automation Start
Automation End
Malware Start
Malware End
AzSQL Start
AzSQL End
WebApps Start
WebApps End
WebAppsBck Start
WebAppsBck End
InfraVmwareASR Start
InfraVmwareASR End

 Email send
```

Do you face it too?
(sorry for this loooong post, please don't TL:DR :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior has been recently changed by Azure Compute team to prevent excessive frequent polling.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same timings as you - approximately 12 seconds per VM for the status retrieval.  With this in mind, and given your VM counts, I'd recommend moving your code into a Workflow so that those 12 second calls can happen concurrently.  I've just tested it with one of my subscriptions and it's dropped your original 1m 44s duration to 0m 15s.

I've removed a bit of your code for simplicity-sake, but hopefully it makes sense and you can fit it back in:

```
<#
.Synopsis
   Gets the status from multiple Azure VMs simultaneously
.EXAMPLE
   Get-VMStatus
#>
function Get-VMStatus
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param ()


    <#
    .Synopsis
       Workflow for getting Azure VM status'
    .DESCRIPTION
       Uses PS Workflow to get Azure VM status' in a concurrent manner, preserving the original code sequence
    .EXAMPLE
       Get-VMStatusWF -VMList (Find-AzureRmResource | Where-Object {$_.ResourceType -like "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines")
    #>
    workflow Get-VMDetailsWF
    {
        Param
        (
            # Param1 help description
            $VMList
        )
        foreach -parallel ($Vm in $VmList) {
            sequence {
                $TimeToGetVM = Measure-Command {$VmDetails = (Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $Vm.ResourceName)}
                Write-Verbose " -Get VM [$($Vm.ResourceName)/$($vm.ResourceGroupName)] $($TimeToGetVM.Minutes):$($TimeToGetVM.Seconds):$($TimeToGetVM.Milliseconds) minutes" -Verbose

                $VmListTags = $VmDetails.Tags
                $TimeToGetThePowa = Measure-Command {$PowerState = ((Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $Vm.ResourceName -Status).Statuses[1].DisplayStatus)}
                Write-Verbose " -Get Status [$($Vm.ResourceName)/$($vm.ResourceGroupName)] $($TimeToGetThePowa.Minutes):$($TimeToGetThePowa.Seconds):$($TimeToGetThePowa.Milliseconds) minutes" -Verbose
            }
        }
    }

    Write-Host "VM Status Start" -ForegroundColor Blue -BackgroundColor White
    $TimeToGetVmList = Measure-Command {$VmList = Find-AzureRmResource | Where-Object {$_.ResourceType -like "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"}}
    Write-Host "`n-Get The VmList $($TimeToGetVmList.Minutes):$($TimeToGetVmList.Seconds):$($TimeToGetVmList.Milliseconds) minutes" -ForegroundColor Green

    $TimeToAllVmStatus = measure-command {Get-VMDetailsWF -VMList $VmList}
    Write-Host "`n---Time to Get all VM status [$($TimeToAllVmStatus.Minutes):$($TimeToAllVmStatus.Seconds):$($TimeToAllVmStatus.Milliseconds)] minutes" -ForegroundColor Green
}


cls
Get-VMStatus
```

Comment: Can the host computer create so many PowerShell sessions? My understanding is, new session gets created in background for all elements in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

here is the official answear from Microsoft:

Below is a summary of the support request for your records:

**Symptom:** 
AzureRm.Compute Cmdlet Get-AzureRmVm execution time is higher than expected (10s~).

**Cause:** 
The Azure Compute team included a software delay/throttling into the API to reduce excessive or frequent polling of the same resources.

Then i move my "Get-AzureRmVM" before the foreach. Just this simple ....

```
#
# Status des VM
#
Write-Output "[$(get-date -Format T)] VM Status Start"
$VmList = Get-AzureRmVm -Status
if ($VmList) {
    $VmProd = 0
    foreach ($Vm in $VmList) {
        if ($Vm.Tags.environment -like "production") {
            $VmDetails = (Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name)
            $VmListTags = $VmDetails.Tags
            $PowerState = $Vm.PowerState
            $OsProfile = $VmDetails |Select-Object @{l = 'OsType'; e = {$_.StorageProfile.osDisk.osType}}
            if ($PowerState -notcontains "VM running") {
                if ($VmListTags -or $VmListTags.schedule -match "`"$dayToday`":" -or $VmListTags.startmwtf -and $WorkingDays -contains $dayToday) {
                    <# Write-Output "match - $($Vm.Name) - $($VmListTags.startmwtf) - $($PowerState)" #>
                    $MyTrashStatus = New-Object PSObject
                    $MyTrashStatus | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Environnement -Value $Vm.Tags.environment
                    $MyTrashStatus | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "RG Name" -Value $vm.ResourceGroupName
                    $MyTrashStatus | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Serveur -Value $Vm.Name
                    $MyTrashStatus | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Systeme -Value $OsProfile."OsType"
                    $MyTrashStatus | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Status -Value $PowerState
                    $vmsPowerState.Add($MyTrashStatus) | Out-Null
                }
            }
            if ($OsProfile."OsType" -match "Windows") {$OsWin += 1} elseif ($OsProfile."OsType" -match "Linux") {$OsLin += 1}
            $VmProd += 1
        }
    }
}
$VmStatusList = "$VmProd VM IaaS ($OsWin Windows & $OsLin Linux)"
if ($vmsPowerState.Count -ge 1) {
    $vmsPowerStateReport = $vmsPowerState | ConvertTo-HTML -fragment
}
else {
    $vmsPowerStateReport = "`t`tToutes les machines sont en etat RUNNING."
}
Write-Output "[$(get-date -Format T)] VM Status End"
```

Thanks guys